# Copy a vertex colour without changing the mesh

Tags: linked-data

I have several meshes that are quite different in just one particular zone. I have made a very nice vertex colour for one of them. It would be nice be able to transfer it to the others as I'm sure that if I attempt to repeat the exercise on each they will all look slightly different. I CAN transfer the vertex colour by selecting all my targets and then the source under Shift and then using Ctrl+L and picking 'Object data'. Unfortunately though they all then have the same mesh. Is it possible to transfer just the colour and keep the mesh structures different? I'm using 2.80

Comment: could you use the colour picker?

Comment: You can try to use DataTransfer modifier and make it pointing to mesh with vertex color as a target to copy vertex color from there to object modifier is on. However this will work only if you have mesh with vertex colors next to the area you want to transfer them to, so you'd need to position objects so that they are intersecting (you can apply modifieir afterwards or use DataTransfer operator in Edit mode if you have other modifiers and can't apply one).